# Issues with Python Date Formatting

Tags: python, date, date-formatting

I am getting error while formatting date in python, any fix:

```
date_time_str = '8/31/2020'
print(datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%d/%m/%y')
expeced result 2019-08-31 00:00:00 
**ValueError: time data '8/31/2020' does not match format '%d/%m/%y'**
```

Answer (score 1):

The format string is incorrect and does not match your string.

```
from datetime import datetime
date_time_str = '8/31/2020'
print(datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%m/%d/%Y'))
```

output

```
2020-08-31 00:00:00
```

of course your expected result with year 2019 is wrong